# selecting parent table in css

Tags: css

suppose I have a nested tables in html like this

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to do style only to the parent table without adding any markup like any class or IDs. so how can I do that only in css.I just want to select the parent table.

Comment: it would probably easier with jQuery, create your style in CSS but select and add that style with jQuery Or another way would be add a class/id to parent table then style it with css (no jQuery needed in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify the parent table in a selector, but you can specify the child tables, so you can style all tables, and then override the style for child tables:

```
table { background: red; }
table table { background: none; }
```

Comment: @user614208 - change 'none' to 'blue' (you can see it better), and use your CSS,HTML from your post. @Guffa's solution will do what you want for any occurrence of a nested table. Including table,table,table

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `table:first`.
But it's advanced selector which I personally wouldn't trust that much in pure CSS. There is also a reason why there are classes and ids so why not use them?